# How to make optimize this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm looking for a help how to simplify my jQuery code and avoid repetitions. I know it can be achieved using OOP, but I don't have enough knowledge how to do this properly. Is there a way to avoid **body.on('click')** repetitions?

**Here is my JavaScript code: (Updated)**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

  /* WordPress Media Uploader
  -------------------------------------------------------*/
  function upload(type) {

    if ( mediaUploader ) {
      mediaUploader.open();
    }

    var mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Select an Image',
      button: {
        text: 'Use This Image'
      },
      multiple: false
    });

    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
      var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      console.log(attachment);
      $('.deo-' + type + '-hidden-input').val(attachment.url);
      $('.deo-' + type + '-media').attr('src', attachment.url);
    });

    mediaUploader.open();

  }

  $('body').on('click', '.deo-image-upload-button', function() {
    upload('image');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.deo-signature-upload-button', function() {
    upload('signature');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.deo-image-delete-button', function(e) {
    $('.deo-image-hidden-input').val('');
    $('.deo-image-media').attr('src', '');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.deo-signature-delete-button', function(e) {
    $('.deo-signature-hidden-input').val('');
    $('.deo-signature-media').attr('src', '');
  });

});
```

Comment: Create a function, like `function upload(type)` and call with `upload('image')` or `upload('signature')`, concatenating that into the class as necessary.

Comment: Thanks :) I've updated my code, is there a way how to improve **$('body').on('click')** repetitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize on click event like this,

```
 $('body').on('click', '.deo-image-upload-button, .deo-signature-upload-button, .deo-image-delete-button, .deo-signature-delete-button', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('deo-image-upload-button')) {
      upload('image');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('deo-signature-upload-button')) {
      upload('signature');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('deo-image-delete-button')) {
      $('.deo-image-hidden-input').val('');
      $('.deo-image-media').attr('src', '');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('deo-signature-delete-button')) {
      $('.deo-signature-hidden-input').val('');
      $('.deo-signature-media').attr('src', '');
    }
  });
```

here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6j2y1t3/) for you to test

Comment: It's working :) Didn't know that it's possible to pass so many classes to click event :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I used attribute selectors to "merge" the similar functions.

It is not tested, but should work.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

  /* WordPress Media Uploader
  -------------------------------------------------------*/
  var imgSign = "";
  var attachment;

  mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
    attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    console.log(attachment);
    $('.deo-'+imgSign+'-hidden-input').val(attachment.url);
    $('.deo-'+imgSign+'-media').attr('src', attachment.url);
  });

  // Image or signature click
  $('body').on('click', '[class*="-upload-button"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).hasClass("deo-image-upload-button") ? imgSign = "image" : imgSign = "signature";

    if ( mediaUploader ) {
      mediaUploader.open();
    }

    // Empty attachements.
    attachment = "";
    var mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Select an Image',
      button: {
        text: 'Use This Image'
      },
      multiple: false
    });



    mediaUploader.open();
  });

  // Image or signature delete
  $('body').on('click', '[class*="-delete-button"]', function(e) {
    $(this).hasClass("deo-image-delete-button") ? imgSign = "image" : imgSign = "signature";
    $('.deo-'+imgSign+'-hidden-input').val('');
    $('.deo-'+imgSign+'-media').attr('src', '');
  });

});
```

I don't know about `mediaUploader.open();`... Is it really usefull to call it that often?

Comment: Thanks. But I have error in console _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?_ . Probably because WordPress is using jQuery 1.4.1.

Comment: mmm... I think it's my bad... I removed the `if` and parenthesis on the ternary operators.

Comment: It's actually works, but the problem that each time I click upload button it creates more and more objects in **attachment** variable :) So first time it;s one object, after 5 clicks it's 5 objects. Check my updated code above it's stores 1 object each time button clicked and image selected. That's how WordPress works :)

Comment: Ok... the `var mediaUploader` block should return in the upload click handler then. I got it out, in the first place, because this handler gets overwrited on each clicks... Which I taught useless... ;)

Comment: Another way would be to leave it out the click handler and just empty the `attachement` variable... Try it. I edited again.